# Use content assist with Explicit type argument in Java compliance level 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, java-7

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 under Java 7, so I want to keep my compiler compliance level in 1.7.

By the way, I'm working together with people who use Eclipse 3.6 (which one does not support compliance level 1.7). So although my JRE is JavaSE-1.7, it compiles codes with 1.6 compliance level.

The problem is, because the compiler under 1.7 does not support implicit type arguments (diamond), it marks error.
For example:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // It's recommended in Java 7, but marked as error in Eclipse 3.6
```

So I hope to set content assist to insert explicit type arguments (old style) rather than implicit type arguments (current style).

Is there a way to change how the content assist works?

Comment: You have to agree on which level is correct if your colleagues are going to use your code and you are going to use their code.  Working at cross-purposes is not going to help build a functional team.  Why can those on Eclipse 3.6 not upgrade to 3.7?  Or, does it really hurt you to work with Java 6 rules?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well... The most of team remains sticky in 3.6, I finally gave up 1.7 compilance level.
thank for your reply.